# NodeJS upgrade failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, version, upgrade, meanjs

I'm using NodeJS 0.12 for my project (MEANJS). After upgrading to NodeJS 4.4, the project seems still running as UI and features are still working in browser, but no logs are printed to console, only these lines are printed out after running project:

```
Running "concurrent:default" (concurrent) task
Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
[nodemon] v1.2.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: app/views/**/*.* gruntfile.js server.js config/**/*.js app/**/*.js
[nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
```

The line '[nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`' is the last line printed out and nothing else. This is strange!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a real answer why NodeJS 4.4.2 not printing logs to console but a workaround.

- NodeJS 0.12.0: Logs are printed to console as usual
- NodeJS 4.4.2: Logs are NOT printed to console
- NodeJS 5.9.1: Logs are printed to console as usual